# Stop the ENTER key from being used in a dojo textarea dijit?

Tags: javascript, dojo

i am trying to limit the height of the dojo's dijit.Textarea by preventing users from hitting the enter key while typing. How can i prevent the enter key from being used? i have the below code but its not wroking.

```
<input type="text" dojoType="dijit.form.Textarea" maxLength="99" onkeydown="return noEnter" />
function noEnter(evt) {  if (evt.keyCode == dojo.keys.ENTER) {
console.log('enter pressed');
evt.stopPropagation();
return false;  }else{
console.log(evt.keyCode + ' pressed');
return true; }}
```

Comment: why dont you compare `evt.keyCode == 13`? and check placing alert is your function called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dojo has a method that can be used for this purpose called stopEvent. Perhaps you could use it like this:

```
<input type="text" dojoType="dijit.form.Textarea" maxLength="99" onkeydown="noEnter" />

function noEnter(e){
    if(e.keyCode == dojo.keys.ENTER){
        dojo.stopEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `dijit.form.SimpleTextarea` which is a straight replacement for `<textarea>`, that is: it does not automatically adjust the height.